# Split a wide figure across facing pages in book

Tags: books, includegraphics

Suppose I have a very wide figure that I’d like to include in a book. Is there any package or other solution for automatically splitting the figure across two pages? The problem is that they need to be facing pages, so a reader does not have to flip back and forth for the full effect.

Comment: Take a look at hvfloat, it has some features for this.

Comment: Thanks very much to you both. Both solutions seem to address exactly what I’m after.